# Check if a jquery mobile listivew already contains a specific item?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

as the title says, is there a function that helps me find out if a listview contains a specific list item that has an id of say hello?

in my javascript i am currently pre loading items in a listview but there is a situation where the same code that adds the items in the listview, it will of coure add and duplicate the items.

i want to do something like this to find id of "hello"

```
if( (#listView).find("hello")  ){
//do nothing
}else{
$(#listView).append('<li id="hello">hello</li>')

}
```

Html:

```
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="fields">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b" data-tap-toggle="false" data-transition="none" > 
    <h1>New Claim</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <ul class="ui-li" data-role="listview" id="listViewId" data-inset="true"  data-scroll="true">
      <li data-role="list-divider">
        <h2 id="itemTitle">divider</h2>
      </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Is this possible? is there some kind of .Find("id") method for a listview?

Answer (score 0):

what is wrong with [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)?

```
if(!$('#listViewId').find("#hello").length){
  // append the element 
}
```

Comment: doesnt work. i also am not trying to find the length but the valie "hello"